# How can get the below result in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

| Col1 | Col2 | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 123 | 6/29 | Success |
| 1234 | 123 | 6/29 | Failed |
| 1204 | 133 | 6/28 | Success |
| 1204 | 133 | 6/28 | Success |
| 1204 | 133 | 6/28 | Success |
| 1224 | 133 | 6/28 | Success |
| 1224 | 133 | 6/28 | Success |
| 1224 | 133 | 6/28 | Failed |
| 1214 | 143 | 6/27 | Success |
| 1214 | 143 | 6/27 | Success |

From the above table, I just wish to get the output as below i.e. If the status is failed in any one of the rows then I wish to get it only failed instance in my query and to get the success status is success in all the columns.

| Col1 | Col2 | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 123 | 6/29 | Failed |
| 1204 | 133 | 6/28 | Success |
| 1224 | 133 | 6/28 | Failed |
| 1214 | 143 | 6/27 | Success |

Using Postgres SQL

Comment: I't not clear to me how to pick a row in the case of success. Are all the rows always identical in each group? What if there are multiple failed ones; which one should be picked?

Comment: What significance does DATE and COL2 have in this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MIN` aggregation function: it will work well as long as "*Failed*" < "*Success*", hence priority will be given to failures. If you need to retrieve dates that have failed at least once (for specific values of "*Col1*" and "*Col2*"), you'll get them, otherwise you'll get the success flag associated.

```
SELECT   Col1, Col2, Date,
         MIN(Status) AS Status
FROM tab
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Date
ORDER BY Date DESC, Status DESC
```

**Note**: the ordering really is optional - if you need it, then keep it, else remove it.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PrsnetzoqR4SKXvdejaKW/0).